# Rails : Create a drop table cascade migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

How do I force a DROP TABLE CASCADE in a Rails 3.2 migration?

Is there an option to pass to drop_table("table_name")?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could always run raw SQL in the migration.

MYSQL:

```
execute "DROP TABLE #{:table_name} CASCADE CONSTRAINTS PURGE"
```

PostgreSQL:

```
execute "DROP TABLE #{:table_name} CASCADE"
```

You can check the documentation of the built-in method `drop_table` [here](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/drop_table).

Comment: That works for MySQL, but the syntax is slightly different for PostgreSQL:  execute "DROP TABLE #{:table_name} CASCADE"

Answer (score 59):

In Rails 4 you can do the following:

```
drop_table :accounts, force: :cascade
```

Answer (score 2):

Put a file in your initializers directory called postgres.rb then did.  This works for rails 4.1 anyway.

```
module ActiveRecord
    module ConnectionAdapters # :nodoc:
        module SchemaStatements
            def drop_table(table_name, options = {})
                execute "DROP TABLE  #{quote_table_name(table_name)} CASCADE"
            end
        end
    end
end
```